# How to send mail to admin email in Google Apps PHP runtime

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email

I am using google apps engine for a php project and its working fine.
But i have a doubt in Mail API.
As per GAE documentaion (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?csw=1#Mail)
i have read the quotas limit
ie.
The quota limit of mail sending in google apps is

```
'Recipients Emailed' 100/Day 
'Admins Emailed'    5,000/Day
```

Now i am using the below method for sending mail

```
use \google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

$image_content_id = '<image-content-id>';

try
{
  $message = new Message();
  $message->setSender("from@google.com");
  $message->addTo("to@google.com");
  $message->setSubject("Example email");
  $message->setTextBody("Hello, world!");
  $message->addAttachment('image.jpg', 'image data', $image_content_id);
  $message->send();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
  // ...
}
```

This working fine.
I am using this method for sending mail to admin email address. Mail successfully send. But the
'Admins Emailed' quota count is not incrementing, 'Recipients Emailed' is incrementing

How can i send mail to admin email in PHP runtime?

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `google\appengine\api\mail\AdminMessage` and `new AdminMessage()` instead to have it count against the admin email quota.